# maven installed and configured properly, but not working with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

i'm new to Maven, a quick question about how get Maven works with Eclipse. Below is what i've done.

1. I installed the Maven on Windows and configured the environment. Test and verify that Maven installed correctly.

```
H:\>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T16:58:10-04:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows".
```

2. In Eclipse, i installed m2e properly. Go to Eclipse Installation Details, i can see m2e, latest build.
3. I created a pom file, including the following dependencies, one is for jbehave, the other is junit.

   `<dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
           <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>4.4</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>`
4. I created a java class, which need import the class from `org.jbehave.core.*` and `org.junit.Test`, as can be seen, both can't be resolved.
5. Go to Eclipse build path, i added jbehave-core-3.9.jar as external jar, and go to the java class, verified that now IDE can resolve the import from `org.jbehave.core.*`. Then i added junit4.jar as external jar too, verified that both error were gone. Looks like the Maven has not be working fine with Eclipse.

I checked many articles on the stackflow, failed to figure out what's wrong with my steps. Simply i just want to run JBehave test with Maven. Looks like the first step is to get Maven works. Could you guys shed some light here? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Right click project, select Maven, Select add maven nature (or something like that).

Comment: it's strange i didn't find the option of Maven when right click project. So maybe it is because i didn't set up Maven with Eclipse properly? Please take a look at the screenshot and drop a few lines here, http://snag.gy/YPfqY.jpg, http://snag.gy/jx0F5.jpg, http://snag.gy/22ES6.jpg, thank you guys!

Comment: It should be under `Configure` I believe, there you can add the maven nature. Also check your eclipse settings and make sure the maven integration is installed correctly (it looks like you only installed the m2e extension development, which is the plugin mechanism for m2e not m2e itself).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse IDE you should create a project with Maven feature (File > New > Maven project). If you already have a project you may add a Maven feature to it (right click > configure > convert to Maven project).

Comment: Good reminder. Indeed, i'm gonna introduce a JBehave demo to my Eclipse, it is based on Maven, so that i have to get to know something about Maven, :) 
Looks like i can't import the demo directly into Eclipse. In this case, which you would suggest me to do? Create an empty project with maven feature and then copy physically the file from demo project one by one? Or get demo project into Eclipse whatever, and then right click to convert to maven project? Please advise further, thanks!

Comment: If this demo project based on Maven you can import it (File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven Project)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1 - In eclipse right click in the project, > Maven > Update project

2 - From command line, in the project folder: mvn eclipse:eclipse

both options will update eclipse with last maven changes

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Sergiosson. Tried a while ago. Option 1, i don't see this Maven feature when right click the project name in Eclipse. Option 2, i did that in command line successfully, see http://snag.gy/eFiZs.jpg. Back to Eclipse, good to see the import was OK now! However, see http://snag.gy/T7NKl.jpg, for some reason, the package was mistaken somewhat. Do you have any idea for this? Thanks again.

Comment: In your second image the class StackScenarions.java has a wrong package name "main.java.de.codecentric.jbehave". It should be de.codecentric.jbehave

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert your project as Maven.
2. Include the url from which you want to download the libraries. [If you are in a secured network, you should check for settings.xml in .m2 directory]
3. Run a maven install for your project. This will download all the libraries listed as dependecies in the pom file to your local machine.
4. Once the above steps are completed, add maven dependecies folder to your project. This can be done by right clicking on project -> properties -> Maven -> uncheck "resolve depedencies from workspace projects".
5. Now you should see the libraries listed in pom file under maven dependencies folder which should resolve your imports in  java classes. [ there is no need to add the library as external jar when you are using Maven]

Hope this helps !